# Laravel 5: How to insert error custom messages array inside validate()

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-5

I want to insert my validation custom messages inside the validate function as shown:

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $rulesemail=['required'=>'Este campo es requerido.'];
        $rulespassword=['min'=>'Debe teclear al menos :min caracteres','required'=>'Favor de teclear su contraseña'];
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email|max:60', 'password' => 'required|min:6'],$rulespassword
        );
```

But i can't get it to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can't with the default `validate()` from the `ValidatesRequests` trait.

However you can override the function in your base controller to change that:

```
public function validate(Request $request, array $rules, array $messages = array())
{
    $validator = $this->getValidationFactory()->make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        $this->throwValidationException($request, $validator);
    }
}
```

And then simply pass the custom messages as third parameter:

```
$rulesemail=['required'=>'Este campo es requerido.'];
$messages=['min'=>'Debe teclear al menos :min caracteres','required'=>'Favor de teclear su contraseña'];
$this->validate($request, [
    'email' => 'required|email|max:60',
    'password' => 'required|min:6'
], $messages);
```

---

Remember that you can also [globally define validation messages](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#custom-error-messages) in a language file. This file is usually located at `resources/lang/xx/validation.php`

Comment: Where exactly is ValidatesRequests?

Comment: `Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests` that's the trait where the `validates()` method comes from. It should be included with `use` in the default base controller `App\Http\Controllers\Controller`

Comment: i saw this same question a few days ago on laravel forum

Answer (score 0):

The validate() method accepts 3 parameters:

Request $request, [$errors], [$messages]

Here's an example of how to customise the error message for a validation condition:

```
    $this->validate(
        $request,
        [
            'first_name'=> 'required',
            'last_name'=> 'required',
            'email' => 'email',
            'date_of_birth' => 'date_format:"Y-m-d"'
        ],
        [
            'date_format' => 'DOB'
        ]
    );
```

PHPStorm provides useful tooltip to instantly see the method options.